# rails google chart bar chart vAxis label using half of width on mobile

Tags: charts, ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-visualization, axis-labels, chartkick

I have a chart that display good on desktop but on mobile/small screen (phone) the label on the v axis is cut off (see image).
[image]

How can i shrink the graph so that the chart uses 50% of the width while the labels use the other 50% of the chartArea so that the label can be shown full length and not cut off.

Here is my code:
CSS

```
#chart_div {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

.html.erb

```
<div id="chart_div" class="col-md-12 nopadding">
  <%= bar_chart $top_10_time48_ht.reverse, id: "bar_chart $top_10_time48_ht", xtitle: "Number of times used", ytitle: "Top Hashtags", colors: ["#C2F4FF"], download: "top_hashtags", refresh: 300,
    library: { 
      chartArea: {left: "15%", top: "30", width: "100%"},
      vAxis: { baselineColor: "#F76161",  gridlines: {Color: "#FFFFFF" }, textStyle: { color: "#76BDD1", fontSize: "12", fontName: "Arial", fontStyle: "normal"}, titleTextStyle: {color: "#F76161", fontSize: "18", padding:"30px" } }, 
      hAxis: { baselineColor: "#F76161" , gridlines: {Color: "#FFFFFF", count: "-1" }, textStyle: { color: "#76BDD1"} , titleTextStyle: {color: "#F76161", fontSize: "16"} } } %>
```

I cannot use the media queries (CSS) as setting for the chart are in .html.erb

**Also** is there a way to have the haxis title on the top of the vertical axis OR position the chart title on the left before the haxis (vertical axis).

Comment: Option chartArea.left controls the width of the labels, chartArea.width the graph...

Comment: Thanks but using the same graph how to make it responsive? Changing the `chartArea.width ` or 'chartArea.left' did not help. Does google chart have a media query option?

Comment: need to also set overall to `width: '100%'` outside of / same level as `chartArea`

Comment: @WhiteHat  is there a way to have the haxis title on the top of the vertical axis OR position the chart title on the left before the haxis (vertical axis)?

Comment: not with standard chart options, but you can modify / add your own, once the `'ready'` event fires -- add chart title, change `'x'` attribute on the `<text>` element